# Perl ( Print $_ ) Incorrect output for characters || forparam loop

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am having the below lines of perl cgi code that suppose to iterate through a file lines and print each line. The issue is what is printed to the stdout for a specific line (in[ 41: ]) is not the same in the file.

Note : This is a perl cgi script.

code :

```
for (param('menu')) {
  /^(1)$/ and do {
                        $Sample="cat /tmp/int_rej_sample.txt";
                        @Sample=`$Sample`;
                        foreach (@Sample) {print $_,p}
   }

   }
```

cat /tmp/int_rej_sample.txt is :

```
 in[ 37: ]<22222222222>
 in[ 39: ]<91>
 in[ 39: ]<91>
 in[ 41: ]<BBBBBBBB44444444>
 in[ 42: ]<9999999999     >
```

output to cgi window is :

```
in[ 37: ]<22222222222>

in[ 39: ]<91>

in[ 39: ]<91>

in[ 41: ]

in[ 42: ]<9999999999 >
```

Comment: What is `p`? Does produce a paragraph tag? If so, no wonder you get paragraphs. (Also, you're probably outputting `Line<p></p>Line<p></p>Line<p></p>` which is not valid HTML.)

Comment: without the p option , the output is printed in one line

Comment: `p($_)` is most likely what you are looking for.

Comment: There are 3 differences between your two outputs: 1) The extra newlines, 2) the missing BBBBBBB44444444 text, and 3) The missing spaces in `<9999999999     >`. Which difference are you referring to as "not being the same"?

Comment: You probably want the `<PRE>` tag around that to preserve newlines instead of adding your own with `p`.

Comment: Also note that CGI and the HTML generating functions in it are (more or less) deprecated: https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE

Comment: Re "*without the p option , the output is printed in one line*", Yes, But `P` is not how one adds line breaks to HTML. Also, you are suffering from [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bugs for not properly converting your text to HTML

Comment: @clamp, No. While that's the proper way you use `p`, that will still create *p*aragraphs

Comment: without the p option , the result is the same , it is just printed in one line like below :in[ 37: ]<226416006278> in[ 39: ]<51> in[ 39: ]<51> in[ 41: ] in[ 42: ]<8797160573 >

Answer (score 0):

I have added a space between "<" and any character after it in the file before entering the print loop .That solved the issue.

```
sed -e 's/</< /g' /tmp/int_rej_sample_dev.txt | sed -e 's/>/ >/g' > /tmp/int_rej_sample.txt
```